# Can you help me identify this English translation of The Gateless Gate?

Tags: reference-request, books, koans

Over the years, as I have seen various commentaries on koans, I've become aware that the quoted text seems to always derive from one of a very few English translations, but the translation concerned is rarely mentioned.

I am no expert on this area of philology and I'm particularly interested in the version which for Hyakujo’s Fox uses the phrasing "fall under the yoke of causation". This was the first translation which I saw, and so somehow canonical to me. I wonder if it is a highly regarded one?

My main interest is in intellectual curiosity, being interested in philology more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer to my own question elsewhere.

The translation I was seeking was prepared by Katsuki Sekida (1903—1987). Sekida was a school teacher by profession, after retiring he dedicated himself to his lifelong interest in Zen, including preparing excellent translations of the Gateless Gate and Blue Cliff Record.